# Intitialzing attributes by a for loop, is this possible?

Tags: java, constructor, attributes

Let's say I have a class with the following code:

```
private String attribute1;
private String attribute2;
private String attribute3;
.....
.....
.....
```

And I want to initialize the attributes by something like:

```
public constructor() {
    int fixedLength = this.getAttributes.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < fixedLength; i++) {
        this.getAttributes.get(i).set("My string is: " + i);
    }
}
```

I know the code is not correct, just for illustration. Is there a way to get the attributes of the current class and loop through the attributes and initialize them?

Comment: Although the code isn't complete, but you can surely use a for loop to initialize multiple variables.

Comment: from where `int fixedLength = this.getAttributes.size();` came from???
do you have an String array named `attributes`??

Comment: No, it's just for illustration, updating the question now

Comment: This can be done using reflection to obtain the list of attributes of an instance and get/set its values.

Comment: Why not just use an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using reflection:

```
MyClass.class.getField("attribute" + i).set(..);
```

Comment: You set the value in *an instance*, not in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `EnumMap`:

```
Map<Attribute,String> attributes = new EnumMap<>(Attribute.class);

enum Attribute {
    One,
    Two,
    Three;
}

public void constructor() {
    for ( Attribute a : Attribute.values() ) {
        attributes.put(a, "My string is: "+a.name());
    }
}
```

Comment: I link every attribute with `@FXML private String attribute...`, and the linking is only possible when the attributes are attributes, and not an enum. Is there a way to list all attributes like I did, but still having the possibility to initialize them by a forloop

Comment: @n00b1990 - You will have to research the JavaFX system for that - I am not familiar with it. Please add the [JavaFX] tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use getDeclaredFileds method to get instance variables

```
public void setAttributes(Object obj) throws Exception {
    Class<?> objClass = obj.getClass();

    Field[] fields = objClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        String name = field.getName();
        field.set(obj, "My Value");

        Object value = field.get(obj);
        System.out.println(name + ": " + value.toString());
    }
}
```